# Unblocking API calls using spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrency, future, spark-structured-streaming

I have an use case where I manipulate streaming datasets, make an external API to enrich the dataset and write it to a sink. What I am doing so far:

```
val simpleDS: Dataset[SimpleModel] = spark
.readstream
.format("kafka")
.option(..)..


def enrich(model: SimpleModel): EnrichedModel = {
    val fut: Future[Int] = lookupLabel(model.id)
    val enrich: Int = Await.result(fut, 5.seconds)

    EnrichModel(model.id, enrich)
}

val enrichedDS = dataset.map(enrich)

enrichedDS
.toJson
.writeStream
.format("kafka")  
.option(..)..
```

Although this works, I am unsure about the `Await.result`part since it blocks. However, `future.onComplete` which is non-blocking, seems to be interested in the side effect (`Unit`) and not on the value returned by the future(`Int`). Is there a way for me to use a non-blocking call to get a value returned by a `Future`?

Comment: So if it works, what is the issue?

Comment: It is blocking if I understand correctly. There might be a non-blocking way to do it..